# What is the difference between using && and , approach to filter inside CALCULATE?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Example 1:

```
Red Contoso Sales Bad Practice :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sales Amount],
    'Product'[Color] = "Red" && 'Product'[Brand] = "Contoso"
)
```

Example 2:

```
Red Contoso Sales :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sales Amount],
    'Product'[Color] = "Red",
    'Product'[Brand] = "Contoso"
)
```

Which is a better approach and why?

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is better practice: "filter columns, don't filter tables".

In the first approach, a crossjoin is created between all possible [Color] and [Brand] values in the table, and then the filter applied.

In the second approach, each column is filtered individually.

More info here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/specifying-multiple-filter-conditions-in-calculate/